# mv raised error message but file was moved

Tags: terminal, osx, mv, darwin

I confess I am not an expert on unix commands but I moved a file to another directory and got an error message - yet the file was moved.  Why is this message '`mv: rename to to /Users/billtubbs/Library/Script Libraries/to: No such file or directory`' raised?  Is it because Library is a protected folder and I was supposed to use `sudo ...`?

This is in a Terminal on Mac OS X 10.13.4:

```
BillsMacBookPro:Scripts billtubbs$ ls ~/Library/'Script Libraries'
BillsMacBookPro:Scripts billtubbs$ mv FileHandlers.scpt to ~/Library/'Script Libraries'
mv: rename to to /Users/billtubbs/Library/Script Libraries/to: No such file or directory
BillsMacBookPro:Scripts billtubbs$ ls
Address Book Scripts                    Terminal scripts
Applications                            Test Script read html page .scpt
Bus Data                                Test script parse html form.scpt
Firefox scripts                         TextDataFromFile.scpt
ListHandlers.scpt                       TextHandlers.scpt
Mail Scripts                            What Time Is It? Old.scpt
Morning routine OLD.scpt                What Time Is It?.app
Morning routine.app                     What time is it?.scpt
Morning routine.scpt                    What time is it?.scptd
NumberHandlers.scpt                     When's the next bus?.scpt
Numbers scripts                         When's the next number 19 bus?.scpt
POF member details.scpt                 When's the next number 20 bus?.scpt
README.md                               When's the next number 25 bus?.scpt
Safari scripts                          mail subject line.scpt
Save mail message to file.scpt          mail_read.scpt
Speak_time.applescript                  save mail_copy.scpt
Speak_time.scpt                         search POF script.scpt
Speak_time.zip
BillsMacBookPro:Scripts billtubbs$ mv TextHandlers.scpt to ~/Library/'Script Libraries'
mv: rename to to /Users/billtubbs/Library/Script Libraries/to: No such file or directory
BillsMacBookPro:Scripts billtubbs$ ls ~/Library/'Script Libraries'
FileHandlers.scpt       TextHandlers.scpt
BillsMacBookPro:Scripts billtubbs$ ls TextH*
ls: TextH*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you said

```
mv  (source filename)  to  (target directory)
```

and Unix commands aren’t English —
you don’t say things like `mv` something **`to`** somewhere. 
`mv` saw

```
mv  (source filename1)  (source filename2)  (target directory)
```

where *`(source filename2)`* was **`to`**,
and the error message says that there’s no such file as **`to`**.

Comment: To complete the answer: The move of the `FileHandlers.scpt` succeeded because `mv` will try to move every named file.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you misunderstand how the `mv` command works. There is no `to` in the parameters thus it is interpreted as a file name but none such file exists.

`man 1 mv`

```
SYNOPSIS
   mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
   mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
   mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
```

Comment: Of course.  I was just doing some AppleScript so the extra 'to' slipped in.  Thanks!  Interesting how it worked anyway.